# How to move files in perl recursively

Tags: 12.04, perl, mv

How can i move all files in a directory to the previous directory in Perl using system command ?

I tried the following method and it showed error

`system('/bin/mv "test/*" , "./"');`

`bash: syntax error near unexpected token '/bin/mv "test/*" , "./"''`

Please help.

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~dmuey/File-Copy-Recursive-0.38/Recursive.pm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl has native methods for this. From [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/%7Edmuey/File-Copy-Recursive-0.38/Recursive.pm):

> **fmove()**
>
> Copies the file then removes the original. You can manage the path the original file is in according to $RemvBase.
>
> **dirmove()**
>
> Uses dircopy() to copy the directory then removes the original. You can manage the path the original directory is in according to $RemvBase.
>
> **rmove()**
>
> Like rcopy() but calls fmove() or dirmove() instead.

And 1 that uses globbing:

> **rmove_glob()**
>
> Like rcopy_glob() but calls rmove() instead of rcopy()

It mentions ...

> **rcopy_glob()**
>
> This function lets you specify a pattern suitable for perl's glob() as the first argument. Subsequently each path returned by perl's glob() gets rcopy()ied.
>
> It returns and array whose items are array refs that contain the return value of each rcopy() call.
>
> It forces behavior as if $File::Copy::Recursive::CPRFComp is true.

---

From the examples in the link:

```
rmove('foo/bar/baz', '/etc/');
# "baz" is removed from foo/bar after it is successfully copied to /etc/
```